# How to write a string like data into Excel using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a random string type data coming from backend. How do I write this non-json data into Excel?

I have used XLSX and filesaver libraries following this example from plunker:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fexcel.service.ts

In this example it works fine as it is a hard-coded json data.

But in my case, the data I am receiving from the backend is something like:

```
0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOwADAP7/CQAG.....
```

This backend data is fine as it is already writing into Excel in another Java application.

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {    
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    console.log('worksheet',worksheet);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, 
                                      SheetNames: ['data'] };
    const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 
'array' });
    //const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
    this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
}

private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
        type: EXCEL_TYPE
    });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
}
```

`XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);` will convert json to Excel, but my data here is not json.

I am getting this error:

> ERROR TypeError: js.forEach is not a function
>   at sheet_add_json (xlsx.js:20696)
>   at Object.json_to_sheet (xlsx.js:20724)

on this line of code:

```
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
```

Can someone please suggest what code to use in place of

```
XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have unstructured, non-json data and you want to write it in an excel file, you have got to manually insert your data cell by cell using the Excel Library you're using.
For example in XLSX you could use :

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [["new data", 1, 2, 3]], {origin: -1});
```

Which inserts a new row at the end of the excel sheet. (here the data added is ['new data', 1,2,3]..